# What does Azure OMS provide other than information what Kubernetes Dashboard provides

Tags: azure, kubernetes

I understand that Kubernetes dashboard can be accessed through `kubectl proxy`.

On Linux, we can run kubectl proxy. 
This will allow you to access the dashboard at http://localhost:8001/ui

additionally if you are using Windows and sshing into the master to use kubectl, you will need to set up remote port forwarding from port 8001 on the master to your host in order to use kubectl proxy. To do this, under PUTTY > Connection > SSH > Tunnels, create a new forwarded port (source local port 8001 to destination 127.0.0.1:8001).

I had a look at Azure OMS as well, but could not figure out what additional features are available on azure OMS!.

Does it give pod/deployment logs as well in its dashboard? because thats the only thing that i dont get in Kubernetes dashboard.

Also do we have control on amount logs that get generated on pods? Meaning if we execute `kubectl logs <<pod-name>>` will result in logs of that pod being displayed in command line. it keeps on loading all the logs into it.
when does it get rolled over? can we control it? Can we access this logs in a single place as we see stats in kubernetes dashboard.

Can we customize Kubernetes dashboard to pull pod logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a really complex question (and very simple at the same time), but kubernetes dashboard is mostly for administering kubernetes (surprisingly). And you can look at the outputs of containers in the kubernetes dashboard (not sure how far back the output goes, though).

OMS is not for administrering kubernetes, it is for monitoring: pulling logs, gathering events and processing those: creating alerts, remediation steps etc.

I will not go into great details about functionality of each of the consoles as it would take too much space and effort.

**TLDR**: So its like asking whats the difference between administration and monitoring. They do slightly overlap but thats about it. OMS - monitoring, kubernetes dashboard - administration.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I understood your point totally. But few more things 1. Can we pull pod logs as well in OMS?   2. Can we customize Kubernetes dashboard to display pod logs as well (I understand its like an admin, but there should be mechanism to do that as well right. For example earlier i have worked with TIBCO Admin where we could pull App logs in admin itself)

Comment: did you read my answer? 1 - yes; 2 - yes, you have option to view logs. also kubernetes dashboard is open source you can do anything you like with it

Comment: Yes i read your answer. I saw your point about pulling logs. Just wanted to make sure we are on the same page about it (about pulling pod logs as well). So we can pull all the logs of Kubernetes objects in OMS itself. Thanks a lot.

Comment: yeah, theres a container solution (targeted at kubernetes specifically) for oms. you can use that